# Insert array into another array

Tags: java, arrays

Writing method to insert a[] into numbers[] at a position stored in variable "location".

```
    public boolean insertArray(int location, double a[])
    {    
        if (length != MAX_CAPACITY)
        {
            numbers[location] = a[];
            length++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Is it possible to pass through an array?

Comment: What's the type of `numbers`?

Comment: Use a loop. You can use `arraycopy` but I guess this is exercise purpose only.

Comment: How can there be so many answers when we don't know the parameters of the question?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) :

```
public static void arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)
```

---

Here is a simple example you can follow to solve your problem :

```
double a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
double b[] = {6, 7, 8};
int local = 5;
double result[] = new double[a.length + b.length];

System.arraycopy(a, 0, result, 0, a.length);
System.arraycopy(b, 0, result, local, b.length);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

**Output**

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]
```

Comment: This only copies the content of one array into another (merge)... I believe that the question asks how to insert an array (i.e. the reference to the array) into a specific location of another array (i.e. two dimensions array)

Comment: @CarlitosWay so for that you makes a down-vote? you can do many things with `System.arraycopy` check my example

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, you can.**

But the Array has to be a Two dimensions `Array`! Example:

```
public static double[][] numbers = new double[MAX_CAPACITY][];

public boolean insertArray(int location, double[] a)
{    
    if (length != MAX_CAPACITY)
    {
        numbers[location] = a;
        length++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can utilise Arrays too.

```
int[] numbers = ...
int[] a = ...

int n = numbers.length;
numbers = Arrays.copyOf(numbers, numbers.length + a.length);
System.arraycopy(a, 0, numbers, n, a.length);
```

In general List and ArrayList are better abstractions with almost the same efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a specific reason you're using arrays instead of a List, such
>   as an ArrayList?

If you're using a java.util.List, then use [`List.addAll(int location, Collection a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28int,%20java.util.Collection%29).

If you're using arrays, then you'll need to perform the array allocation and copying yourself. Here's an [example implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.addAll%28int%2Cjava.util.Collection%29) of `ArrayList.addAll(int, Collection)` from OpenJDK:

```
// Copyright 1997-2007 Sun Microsystems, Inc.
public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> c) {
    rangeCheckForAdd(index);

    Object[] a = c.toArray();
    int numNew = a.length;
    ensureCapacity(size + numNew);  // Increments modCount

    int numMoved = size - index;
    if (numMoved > 0)
        System.arraycopy(elementData, index, elementData, index + numNew,
                         numMoved);

    System.arraycopy(a, 0, elementData, index, numNew);
    size += numNew;
    return numNew != 0;
}
```